# How to interpret error "elements..... must be named" when sourcing an R6 class?

Tags: r, curl, r6

Code snippets taken from [chernan's sample REST queries](https://github.com/chernan/RESTfulAccessExamples/blob/master/bioDBnet.Rmd) are utilized to define an R6 class one private method, two public attributes and a constructor:

```
library(R6)
library(RCurl)
library(RJSONIO)
Symbol <- R6Class("Symbol",
  private = list(
    #
    # define a generic function to send an HTTP GET request
    #
    rcurl_request <- function(service_url, parameters) {
      # Collapse all parameters into one string
      all_parameters <- paste(
        sapply(names(parameters), 
               FUN=function(param_name, parameters) {
                 paste(param_name, paste(parameters[[param_name]], collapse=','), collapse='', sep='=')
               }, 
               parameters),
        collapse="&")
      # Paste base URL and parameters
      requested_url <- paste0(service_url, all_parameters)
      # Encode URL (in case there would be any space character for instance)
      requested_url <- URLencode(requested_url)
      # Start request to service
      response <- getURL(requested_url, .opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE))
      return(response)
    }
  ),                
  public = list(
    species = NULL,
    bdbnJSON = NULL,
    initialize = function(symbol, bdbSpecies){
      parameters <- list(method="dbfind", 
                         inputValues=symbol,
                         output="geneid",
                         taxonId=bdbSpecies,
                         format="col"
      )
      base_url = "https://biodbnet-abcc.ncifcrf.gov/webServices/rest.php/"
      json_url = paste0(base_url, "biodbnetRestApi.json?")    
      self$bdbnJSON <- rcurl_request(json_url, parameters)
    }
  )                  
)
```

Now I source the containing file and get a strange error.

```
> source("parseSymbol.R")
Error in R6Class("Symbol", private = list(rcurl_request <- function(service_url,  : 
  All elements of public, private, and active must be named.
```

This looks like it should mean that I tried to do something like "self$[something I didn't declare in public or private] <- new value" but there appears to be no such mistake.  What is going on here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you have to use the `=` operator within the `list` instead of `<-`.
So in your case use `rcurl_request = function(service_url, parameters) {` to solve the problem.

The error message is not very informative, I was having this problem already several times.

Comment: Thanks @drmariod, it works perfectly now.  In fact, I had given up and decided to implement in S4 (this class is part of a much larger library) and run into so many headaches with the S4 constructor syntax.  Glad to be back on the R6 train now!